# android:screenOrientation ? Can you go landscape only on high resolution devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a technique to allow landscape only on large device?

I can set the manifest.xml file for the activity to rotate based on the sensor, eg 
android:screenOrientation = "sensor"    but this does not provide the behavior I'd like.

For instanced I'd like to allow a user to go to Landscape mode in a tablet device, but not on smaller resolution device (because the UI would look awful).

From what I can tell, there is no way to respond dynamically (eg at run time) if an orientation is acceptable. Or is there?

Am I missing something?   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Could you do it with the resource folders:

For smaller landscape - default:

```
  /layout/main.xml
```

main.xml root layout: orientation="portrait" (forcing portrait here instead of in the manifest)

For high res allowing portrait:

```
 /layout-port-hdpi/main.xml
```

main.xml will be portrait hdpi only

This is the article you can get idea's from: [ResourceTypes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes)

Comment: Keep in mind that high res is relative. My xoom is considered medium res.

Comment: Yes it's just one filter, you could use -large or -xlarge or combine -large-hdpi. Here's a Bookmark on the page I already linked: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenSizeQualifier

Answer (score 1):

Providing resources specific to large streens is built into the Android resource XML. Resource directories may be suffixed with `-<suffix>` to qualify that they are specific to a class of device capability, locality, time of day, and more. Specifically, you'd be interested in the screen size qualifier, which supports the values `large` and `xlarge` for just the purpose of creating special conditions for screens larger than 4 and 7 inches respectively.

For specifics on how to support multiple screen sizes, see [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) which comes directly from the developer manual.